# Gradle evaluates using empty build file

Tags: gradle

I am getting below error when trying to run `grdle tasks` command

```
Evaluating project ':Project1' using empty build file.
Evaluating project ':Project2' using empty build file.
```

I have multiproject build

`Main
|--Root
|----Project1
|----Project2
|--build
|----settings.gradle
|----build.gradle
|----sub-project.gradle`

and below is my settings.gradle

```
File modulesDir = new File("${rootProject.projectDir}/../Root").canonicalFile
modulesDir.eachFile {
    include it.name
}
rootProject.children.each { 
    it.projectDir = new File(modulesDir, it.name) 
    it.buildFileName = './sub-project.gradle'
}
```

---

this line is not working

```
it.buildFileName = './sub-project.gradle'
```

the sub-project.gradle is not getting assigned to sub project.

whats the problem? How can one assign actual build file to project?

Answer (score 0):

Your `settings.gradle` should include projects with the `:`  So for example you can include the projects as

```
def modulesRoot = new File("$rootProject.projectDir.parentFile/Root")
File[] moduleDirs = modulesRoot.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    boolean accept(File path) {
        return path.isDirectory()
    }
})
moduleDirs.each {
    include ":$it.name"
    project(":$it.name").projectDir = new File(modulesRoot, it.name)
    project(":$it.name").buildFileName = new File(settingsDir, 'sub-project.gradle')
}
```

Also a more common pattern is to include a `build.gradle` in the project that needs to be built by the `sub-project.gradle`

To do this create the file `Root/Project1/build.gradle` and in that file add the line `apply from: "$project.rootProject.absolutePath/sub-project.gradle"`

This is a better approach then assigning the build file to the project

Comment: I am getting `java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
 > The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect` although the path is correct